# invalid use of member ‘xx::x’ in static member function

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, computational-geometry

I want to apply selection operation in a 3d viewer (using qt-creator)

any.h file:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
class any
{
public:
    any();
     int board[3][3];
   void init(void);
  static void drawSquares(GLenum mode);
  static void processHits (GLint hits, GLuint buffer[]);
   static  void pickSquares(int button, int state, int x, int y);
   static void display(void);
  static void reshape(int w, int h);
};
```

any.ccp file :

```
#include "any.h"

any::any()
{

}

void any:: init(void)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < 3; j ++)
         board[i][j] = 0;
   glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

void any:: drawSquares(GLenum mode)
{
   GLuint i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if (mode == GL_SELECT)
         glLoadName (i);
      for (j = 0; j < 3; j ++) {
         if (mode == GL_SELECT)
            glPushName (j);
         glColor3f ((GLfloat) i/3.0, (GLfloat) j/3.0,(GLfloat) board[i][j]/3.0);
         glRecti (i, j, i+1, j+1);
         if (mode == GL_SELECT)
            glPopName ();
      }
   }
}

/*  processHits prints out the contents of the
 *  selection array.
 */
void any:: processHits (GLint hits, GLuint buffer[])
{
   unsigned int i, j;
   GLuint ii, jj, names, *ptr;

   printf ("hits = %d\n", hits);
   ptr = (GLuint *) buffer;
   for (i = 0; i < hits; i++) { /*  for each hit  */
      names = *ptr;
      printf (" number of names for this hit = %d\n", names);
         ptr++;
      printf("  z1 is %g;", (float) *ptr/0x7fffffff); ptr++;
      printf(" z2 is %g\n", (float) *ptr/0x7fffffff); ptr++;
      printf ("   names are ");
      for (j = 0; j < names; j++) { /*  for each name */
         printf ("%d ", *ptr);
         if (j == 0)  /*  set row and column  */
            ii = *ptr;
         else if (j == 1)
            jj = *ptr;
         ptr++;
      }
      printf ("\n");
      board[ii][jj] = (board[ii][jj] + 1) % 3;
   }
}

#define BUFSIZE 512

void any:: pickSquares(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
   GLuint selectBuf[BUFSIZE];
   GLint hits;
   GLint viewport[4];

   if (button != GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON || state != GLUT_DOWN)
      return;

   glGetIntegerv (GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

   glSelectBuffer (BUFSIZE, selectBuf);
   (void) glRenderMode (GL_SELECT);

   glInitNames();
   glPushName(0);

   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glPushMatrix ();
   glLoadIdentity ();
/*  create 5x5 pixel picking region near cursor location      */
   gluPickMatrix ((GLdouble) x, (GLdouble) (viewport[3] - y),
                  5.0, 5.0, viewport);
   gluOrtho2D (0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 3.0);
   drawSquares (GL_SELECT);

   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
   glPopMatrix ();
   glFlush ();

   hits = glRenderMode (GL_RENDER);
   processHits (hits, selectBuf);
   glutPostRedisplay();
}

void any:: display(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   drawSquares (GL_RENDER);
   glFlush();
}

void any:: reshape(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluOrtho2D (0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 3.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}
```

main file:

```
#include <any.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
 //  glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize (100, 100);
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
   any* an=new any();
   an->init();

   glutMouseFunc (an->pickSquares);
   glutReshapeFunc (an->reshape);
   glutDisplayFunc(an->display);
   glutMainLoop();
   return app.exec();
}
```

the error :

```
../untitled/any.cpp:60:24: error: invalid use of member ‘any::board’ in static member function
```

when I try to make board static it shows a lot of errors about :

```
 26: undefined reference to `any::board'
```

Comment: any::board is a member of class any. the static function doesn't have access to class members

Comment: You have to **define** `any::board` if you make it static. All you've done so far is **declare** it. Add this code after your `any` class `int any::board[3][3];`.

Comment: Something to think about. When you have a class where **everything** is static, what's the point of having a class at all? You could do the same, more simply, by just having a bunch of functions and global variables.

Comment: @john thanks a lot ,but after resolving board problem it shows the following error : Loadable section ".note.gnu.property" outside of ELF segments
realloc(): invalid pointer

Comment: @user3019180 That's very obscure, sorry I have no idea on that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Static function cannot access non-static variables***

In your source code, compiler will flash an error i.e. illegal reference to non-static member `any::board`.

Hence, accessing non-static members from static method in `C++` programming is not possible.

`static` method memories will be create once without creating an instance of `class`. so you cannot use of a `non-static` class members in a `static` method, because `non-static` members has no memory already in `static` methods.

Please define your methods as `non-static` or use of `static` members in your class.

Please check out [this link](https://www.interviewsansar.com/2017/02/26/can-static-function-access-non-static-variables-cpp/).

Comment: thanks a lot,but after resolving board problem it shows the following error : Loadable section ".note.gnu.property" outside of ELF segments
realloc(): invalid pointer

Comment: Notice: please add the following libraries to your `.pro` file in qt creator : `LIBS += -lGLU`
`LIBS += -lGL`
`LIBS += -lglut`
`LIBS += -lGLU`

Answer (score 1):

`board` is an instance member. You can't use it in a static method like `drawSquares`. You either need to make `board` a static member too, or, more likely, make `drawSquares` non-static.

Comment: Same should be said of `processHits`, `pickSquares`, `display`. Only `reshape` seems to be genuinely static. but then it's not clear why `reshape` is in the `any` class at all.

Comment: Since these functions are being used as call backs they have to be static. It's the old problem of how to you pass a C++ method to an API that's expecting a function pointer.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks a lot , ,but after resolving board problem it shows the following error : Loadable section ".note.gnu.property" outside of ELF segments
realloc(): invalid pointer